# Util function to chain multiple promise functions along with non promise functions at the end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, promise

I have a solution handy for pure promise functions. But I need a way to chain a set of promise functions and the last 'then' would call three other non-promise functions.

**Below is what I tried**

```
function chainMyPromises(promiseFunction, promiseArray){
    if(!promiseArray.length){
       return;
    }

  promiseFunction.then(()=>{
    const currentFunc = promiseArray.shift()
    return chainMyPromises(currentFunc(), promiseArray);
   });
}

const promiseArray = [functionOne, functionTwo, functionThree, functionFour];

function firstPromise(){
  return Promise.resolve(true);
}

chainMypromises(firstpromise, promiseArray);
```

**Below is my function that has some promise based functions, the last 'then' checks for a response and call three non promise based function.**

```
function consolidatedReport(param1, param2){

   const somedata = param1.data;
   const someOtherData = param2.data;

  if(true){ 
     doThisthing(); 
   }

  return promiseChainBegin(somedata, someOtherData)
    .then(response => response && functionOne(somedata, someOtherData)
    .then(response => response && functionTwo(somedata, someOtherData)
    .then(response => response && functionThree(somedata, someOtherData)
    .then(response => response && functionFour(somedata, someOtherData)
    .then(response => {
       if(response) {
           notApromiseFuncOne(somedata)(someOtherData);
           notApromiseFuncTwo(somedata)(someOtherData);
           notApromiseFuncThree(somedata)(someOtherData);
        } else{
           notApromiseFailCase(someOtherData);
        }
    });
}
```

The last 'then' calls three functions that are not promise based. I need a way to chain these and tidy them up. Please suggest the best way to refactor them.

Comment: so `notApromiseFuncOne` etc are not asynchronous? then there is no problem

Comment: @JaromandaX how? can u gimme an example. My Util function works fine if it's all gonna be async functions but since I have non-async functions at the end. Facing a bummer there.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use something like `Promise.all()` like so:

```
    var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
    var promise2 = 42;
    var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
    });

    Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
      console.log(values);
    }).catch(function(err){
      //If there is an execption it would be handled here
    });
    // expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```

This is a much clearner way of handling multiple promises, you can then execute all of your non promise based function in the last `.then()`